# How to install Tensorflow-GPU on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, installation, gpu

How to install Tensorflow-GPU on ubuntu 16.04
I am using GeForce-710M GPU on my laptop and UBUNTU 16.04 LTS. installing tensorflow-gpu is too hard for me and i searched a lot, but i didn't get a good solution for my problem, please help.
for example i tried this command on ubuntu 16.04:

pip install tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this hardly relates to programming. Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/?

Comment: i searched there, but didn't find an usefull answer

Comment: I searched alot and i found that Geforce-710M GPU doesn' t support tensorflow-gpu, and so i cann't install tensorflow-gpu on my laptop.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77205609/6013016) might help