# How to install tensorflow-gpu from anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have run some very basic steps ([tensorflow-gpu](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow-gpu) is currently at 2.12.1):

```
conda create --name py311_tf212 python=3.11 numpy numba scipy spyder pandas
conda activate py311_tf212
time conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu
```

After 3 hours of thinking and printing a few thousand lines of package dependencies, the installation fails.
My system features are:

- Ubuntu 18.04,
- feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27,
- CUDA 11.8,
- Nvidia driver 520.61.05.

I'm not sure what other information is relevant. I'd be happy to get any tips.

**Edit 2023-12-19**, I gave this a new go. This time I specified the conda-forge channel at the env creation step:

```
$ time conda create --name py311_tf2_test -c conda-forge python=3.11 numpy numba scipy spyder pandas tensorflow-gpu
...
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
...
Package expat conflicts for:
numpy -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.13'] -> expat[version='>=2.2.9,<3.0.0a0|>=2.3.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.1,<3.0a0|>=2.4.8,<3.0a0|>=2.4.9,<3.0a0|>=2.5.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.7,<3.0a0']
scipy -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.13'] -> expat[version='>=2.2.9,<3.0.0a0|>=2.3.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.1,<3.0a0|>=2.4.8,<3.0a0|>=2.4.9,<3.0a0|>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
pandas -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.13'] -> expat[version='>=2.2.9,<3.0.0a0|>=2.3.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.1,<3.0a0|>=2.4.8,<3.0a0|>=2.4.9,<3.0a0|>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
spyder -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> expat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
...
Package typing_extensions conflicts for:
numba -> importlib-metadata -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.6.4']
spyder -> ipython[version='>=8.12.2,<9.0.0,!=8.17.1'] -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.10|>=3.10.0|>=3.7|>=3.6.4']
...
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - feature:/linux-64::__unix==0=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__unix==0=0
  - numba -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - numpy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pandas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - python=3.11 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - scipy -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - spyder -> ipython[version='>=8.12.2,<9.0.0,!=8.17.1'] -> __linux
  - tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==2.15.0=cuda118py39h5387621_0 -> __cuda
  - tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==2.6.2=cuda111py37hf54207c_2 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.27

real    32m40.392s
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this, is the installed glibc version an issue here? Most packages seem to be happy with 2.17 or newer. Oddly tensorflow-gpu has dependencies `tensorflow==2.15.0` and `tensorflow==2.6.2`.

Comment: Please try again using only Conda Forge - it is a standalone channel and is not intended to be mixed with packages from `defaults` channels. Alternatively, install everything from `defaults`. Using `mamba` or turning on the `libmamba` solver in Conda will be faster. Also, declare everything in the `conda create` directive, rather than iteratively; or better, use a YAML. If there are still issues, edit the question.

Comment: I tried using conda forge at the `conda create` stage and to install everything at once, but it didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps CUDA isn't detected? When you check `conda info`, is `__cuda` showing up in your virtual packages section? I'm not having any solve problems with mamba when mocking your system (`CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA=11.8 CONDA_OVERRIDE_GLIBC=2.27 mamba create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.11 numpy numba scipy spyder pandas tensorflow-gpu`).

Comment: My virtual packages are `__glibc=2.27=0`, `__unix=0=0` and `__archspec=1=x86_64`, nothing CUDA-related. It seems that we are getting closer to a solution :) Can you suggest any next steps? I'm going to try `mamba` as well.

Comment: I believe you need to ensure `nvcc` is on PATH.

Comment: Ahaa! "Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit". But tensorflow-gpu works fine when installed from pip. And I found its binary from `/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin/nvcc`, but clearly it isn't in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you already tried many things, maybe it's better to reinstall your ubuntu and start over?

Anyways

1. The first thing you need is to install **nvidia drivers**, and you can install it via **Sowfware and Updates**:
   [image]

Just select the one with **(proprietary, tested)**, in your case it might be higher such as 535 or whatever. You can check if nvidia-drivers is installed by running this command:

```
nvidia-smi
```

2. Install Anaconda (run these commands):

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
shasum -a 256 Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

[Source for installing Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/linux/)

3. Create conda environment and activate it by running these commands:

```
conda create -n any_name python=3.9
conda activate any_name
```

4. Run following comment to install lates pip version:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

5. Lastly, run this:

```
# For installing tensorflow-gpu
pip install 'tensorflow[and-cuda]'
```

[Source for installing tensorflow-gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

You might check if tensorflow is installed and using gpu by running running the following command on your editor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Done!

Comment: Umm, so you recommend to install tensorflow from `pip` rather than `conda`? I alraedy have working drivers and matching CUDA, with python 3.8 and TF 2.5. I think I installed that TF from pip as well.

Comment: I'm just saying this way is possible. But, please suggest how to install with conda as well, so that people (including me) would get benefit 

Comment: For those coming across this, yes installing with pip may be necessary. For whatever reason, the conda build seems bugged. The issue you will have though is if you upgrade conda it may break your env. So keep a requirement.txt so you can easily rebuild after a conda upgrade. This solution has worked for me, I have done it twice using WSL Ubuntu. One difference is I am using Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `conda install anaconda::tensorflow-gpu`, which worked for me when conda-forge did not. Not sure why.

Comment: Anaconda channel is at version 2.6.0 (released in August 2021, 2.5 years ago), while conda-force is at 2.15.0.