# How to override system-level characteristics in Conda solve?

Tags: conda

To troubleshoot failing Conda solves for others, I will rerun their solve using a **subdir** override, e.g.,

```bash
# mimic linux-64
CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 mamba create -n foo python=3.11
```

Recently, I'm encountering more situations where users have other system-level characteristics like CUDA version or GLIBC versions that seem to be the issue. For a concrete example, how does one mimic the CUDA v11.8 and GLIBC v2.27 reported by the user having trouble solving for `tensorflow-gpu` in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77202380/570918)?

Naïvely trying:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 mamba create -n foo python=3.11 tensorflow-gpu
```

results in unsolvable situation, that specifically lists reasons:

- *"[requires] `__glibc >=2.17` , which is missing on the system;"*
- *"[requires] `__cuda`, which is missing on the system;"*

However, I suspect this is merely a problem on my system and not something that gives me insight into what someone on a native system would encounter.

**How can such characteristics be mimicked on a system without them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Virtual Packages

These system-level characteristics are called *virtual packages* and are described in the Conda User Guide, under [Tasks > Managing virtual packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-virtual.html). Checking `conda info` will show a `virtual package:` section, that lists the currently detected system characteristics. For example,

```bash
$ conda info
# [abridged output]

virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                   __osx=11.7.10=0
                   __unix=0=0
```

### Overriding virtual packages

The [documentation describes](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-virtual.html#overriding-detected-packages) that virtual packages can be overridden with the `CONDA_OVERRIDE_[name]` environment variable. For example, we can mimic a specific CUDA version with:

```bash
$ CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA=11.8 conda info
# [abridged output]

virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                   __cuda=11.8=0
                   __osx=11.7.10=0
                   __unix=0=0
```

### Overriding in a solve

Attempting the solve from OP will work when overriding CUDA and GLIBC virtual packages:

```bash
$ CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 \
  CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA=11.8 \
  CONDA_OVERRIDE_GLIBC=2.27 \
  mamba create -n foo python=3.11 tensorflow-gpu

Looking for: ['python=3.11', 'tensorflow-gpu']

warning  libmamba linux version not found, defaulting to '0'
conda-forge/linux-64                                        Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
bioconda/linux-64                                           Using cache
bioconda/noarch                                             Using cache
pkgs/main/linux-64                                            No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/r/linux-64                                               No change
Transaction

  Prefix: /Users/user/miniforge3/envs/foo

  Updating specs:

   - python=3.11
   - tensorflow-gpu


  Package                         Version  Build                    Channel           Size
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  Install:
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  + python_abi                       3.11  4_cp311                  conda-forge        6kB
  + _libgcc_mutex                     0.1  conda_forge              conda-forge        3kB
  + libstdcxx-ng                   13.2.0  h7e041cc_3               conda-forge        4MB
  + ld_impl_linux-64                 2.40  h41732ed_0               conda-forge      705kB
  + ca-certificates            2023.11.17  hbcca054_0               conda-forge      154kB
  + libgomp                        13.2.0  h807b86a_3               conda-forge      422kB
  + _openmp_mutex                     4.5  2_gnu                    conda-forge       24kB
  + libgcc-ng                      13.2.0  h807b86a_3               conda-forge      774kB
  + libaec                          1.1.2  h59595ed_1               conda-forge       35kB
  + libev                            4.33  hd590300_2               conda-forge      113kB
  + libgfortran5                   13.2.0  ha4646dd_3               conda-forge        1MB
  + giflib                          5.2.1  h0b41bf4_3               conda-forge       77kB
  + c-ares                         1.24.0  hd590300_0               conda-forge      156kB
  + ncurses                           6.4  h59595ed_2               conda-forge      884kB
  + xz                              5.2.6  h166bdaf_0               conda-forge      418kB
  + libzlib                        1.2.13  hd590300_5               conda-forge       62kB
  + libffi                          3.4.2  h7f98852_5               conda-forge       58kB
  + bzip2                           1.0.8  hd590300_5               conda-forge      254kB
  + snappy                         1.1.10  h9fff704_0               conda-forge       39kB
  + openssl                         3.2.0  hd590300_1               conda-forge        3MB
  + libjpeg-turbo                   3.0.0  hd590300_1               conda-forge      619kB
  + flatbuffers                   23.5.26  h59595ed_1               conda-forge        2MB
  + cudatoolkit                    11.8.0  h4ba93d1_12              conda-forge      716MB
  + keyutils                        1.6.1  h166bdaf_0               conda-forge      118kB
  + re2                        2023.03.02  h8c504da_0               conda-forge      201kB
  + libabseil                  20230125.3  cxx17_h59595ed_0         conda-forge        1MB
  + icu                              73.2  h59595ed_0               conda-forge       12MB
  + libuuid                        2.38.1  h0b41bf4_0               conda-forge       34kB
  + libnsl                          2.0.1  hd590300_0               conda-forge       33kB
  + libexpat                        2.5.0  hcb278e6_1               conda-forge       78kB
  + libgfortran-ng                 13.2.0  h69a702a_3               conda-forge       24kB
  + libedit                  3.1.20191231  he28a2e2_2               conda-forge      124kB
  + readline                          8.2  h8228510_1               conda-forge      281kB
  + tk                             8.6.13  noxft_h4845f30_101       conda-forge        3MB
  + zstd                            1.5.5  hfc55251_0               conda-forge      545kB
  + zlib                           1.2.13  hd590300_5               conda-forge       93kB
  + libprotobuf                   3.21.12  hfc55251_2               conda-forge        2MB
  + libpng                         1.6.39  h753d276_0               conda-forge      283kB
  + libsqlite                      3.44.2  h2797004_0               conda-forge      846kB
  + libnghttp2                     1.58.0  h47da74e_1               conda-forge      632kB
  + libssh2                        1.11.0  h0841786_0               conda-forge      271kB
  + libopenblas                    0.3.25  pthreads_h413a1c8_0      conda-forge        6MB
  + krb5                           1.21.2  h659d440_0               conda-forge        1MB
  + libgrpc                        1.54.3  hb20ce57_0               conda-forge        6MB
  + libblas                         3.9.0  20_linux64_openblas      conda-forge       14kB
  + libcurl                         8.5.0  hca28451_0               conda-forge      389kB
  + libcblas                        3.9.0  20_linux64_openblas      conda-forge       14kB
  + liblapack                       3.9.0  20_linux64_openblas      conda-forge       14kB
  + hdf5                           1.14.3  nompi_h4f84152_100       conda-forge        4MB
  + cuda-version                     11.8  h70ddcb2_2               conda-forge       21kB
  + tzdata                          2023c  h71feb2d_0               conda-forge     Cached
  + nccl                         2.19.4.1  h6103f9b_0               conda-forge      118MB
  + cudnn                       8.8.0.121  hcdd5f01_4               conda-forge      479MB
  + python                         3.11.7  hab00c5b_0_cpython       conda-forge       31MB
  + wheel                          0.42.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + setuptools                     68.2.2  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + pip                            23.3.2  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge        1MB
  + cached_property                 1.5.2  pyha770c72_1             conda-forge     Cached
  + pysocks                         1.7.1  pyha2e5f31_6             conda-forge     Cached
  + attrs                          23.1.0  pyh71513ae_1             conda-forge     Cached
  + pycparser                        2.21  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + packaging                        23.2  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + blinker                         1.7.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       18kB
  + pyjwt                           2.8.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       25kB
  + pyasn1                          0.5.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       64kB
  + cachetools                      5.3.2  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       15kB
  + click                           8.1.7  unix_pyh707e725_0        conda-forge       84kB
  + zipp                           3.17.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       19kB
  + charset-normalizer              3.3.2  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + idna                              3.6  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + certifi                    2023.11.17  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + gast                            0.5.4  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       24kB
  + absl-py                         2.0.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge      105kB
  + typing_extensions               4.9.0  pyha770c72_0             conda-forge       36kB
  + termcolor                       2.3.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       12kB
  + six                            1.16.0  pyh6c4a22f_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + python-flatbuffers            23.5.26  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       34kB
  + keras                          2.15.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge      900kB
  + cached-property                 1.5.2  hd8ed1ab_1               conda-forge        4kB
  + pyasn1-modules                  0.3.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       96kB
  + rsa                               4.9  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + importlib-metadata              7.0.0  pyha770c72_0             conda-forge       26kB
  + pyu2f                           0.1.5  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + google-pasta                    0.2.0  pyh8c360ce_0             conda-forge       43kB
  + astunparse                      1.6.3  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       16kB
  + markdown                        3.5.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       77kB
  + brotli-python                   1.1.0  py311hb755f60_1          conda-forge      351kB
  + markupsafe                      2.1.3  py311h459d7ec_1          conda-forge       27kB
  + multidict                       6.0.4  py311h459d7ec_1          conda-forge       61kB
  + frozenlist                      1.4.1  py311h459d7ec_0          conda-forge       61kB
  + tensorboard-data-server         0.7.0  py311h63ff55d_1          conda-forge        5MB
  + numpy                          1.26.2  py311h64a7726_0          conda-forge        8MB
  + protobuf                      4.21.12  py311hcafe171_0          conda-forge      389kB
  + wrapt                          1.14.1  py311hd4cff14_1          conda-forge       61kB
  + grpcio                         1.54.3  py311hcafe171_0          conda-forge      800kB
  + cffi                           1.16.0  py311hb3a22ac_0          conda-forge      300kB
  + yarl                            1.9.3  py311h459d7ec_0          conda-forge      122kB
  + h5py                           3.10.0  nompi_py311hebc2b07_101  conda-forge        1MB
  + ml_dtypes                       0.2.0  py311h320fe9a_2          conda-forge      703kB
  + cryptography                   41.0.7  py311hcb13ee4_1          conda-forge        2MB
  + urllib3                         2.1.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + werkzeug                        3.0.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge      242kB
  + aiosignal                       1.3.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + opt_einsum                      3.3.0  pyhc1e730c_2             conda-forge       58kB
  + oauthlib                        3.2.2  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       92kB
  + pyopenssl                      23.3.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge      127kB
  + requests                       2.31.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge     Cached
  + requests-oauthlib               1.3.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       22kB
  + aiohttp                         3.9.1  py311h459d7ec_0          conda-forge      798kB
  + google-auth                    2.25.2  pyhca7485f_0             conda-forge      103kB
  + google-auth-oauthlib            1.2.0  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge       26kB
  + tensorboard                    2.15.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0             conda-forge        5MB
  + tensorflow-base                2.15.0  cuda118py311h0476658_0   conda-forge      145MB
  + tensorflow-estimator           2.15.0  cuda118py311heba7942_0   conda-forge      715kB
  + tensorflow                     2.15.0  cuda118py311hfabe020_0   conda-forge       39kB
  + tensorflow-gpu                 2.15.0  cuda118py311h0240f8b_0   conda-forge       38kB

  Summary:

  Install: 116 packages

  Total download: 2GB

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```